# SQL query returns ORA-01805: possible error in date/time operation error

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am trying to execute an SQL query inside a python code and getting

> ORA-01805: possible error in date/time operation error.

How do I fix this issue? I have downloaded the latest oracle instant client file..how am I supposed to change the date?

Comment: The error is in your sql, but without code it's hard to say what it is

Comment: You can fix this by correcting the error, or by not running the query (or the python code inside which it is wrapped).

Comment: If you have ORACLE_HOME set, then unset it.  This can cause some clashes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth to read a Database Globalization Support Guide from Oracle. Then you will be informed that for a time zone aware clients there is a a little nuance that you need to take into account. Only some of clients can connect with different version of time zone files - it works for Oracle Database 11g and later and for clients such as OCI, JDBC, Pro*C, and SQL*Plus. For other clients:

> it should be assumed that such clients cannot operate with a database
> server with a different time zone file than the client

In general OCI is supported in mixed mode, so `cx_oracle` should work. But... I ran into problems with Oracle 11g and `cx_oracle` (not remember the version). The solution was to install instant client in exact matching version to the database. When I installed instant client in 11.2 version instead of 12.2 the error disappeared.

So look for a database version:

```
select * from v$version;
```

and find matching instant client. It should work.

You can check time zone file version for a database with that query:

```
-- user SYS or anyone with SYSDBA privilege can query that view:
select *
from v$timezone_file;

-- example output:
FILENAME         VERSION
timezlrg_14.dat  14
```

Then you can check instant client version (on Linux):

```
# your instant client path could be different
$ cd /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin
$  ./genezi -v
Client Shared Library 64-bit - 12.2.0.1.0

System name:    Linux
Release:        4.15.0-121-generic
Version:        #123-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 16:16:40 UTC 2020
Machine:        x86_64

Operating in Instant Client mode.

Small timezone file = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/oracore/zoneinfo/timezone_26.dat
Large timezone file = /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/oracore/zoneinfo/timezlrg_26.dat
```

In the example above - database has time zone file in version 14 and the client has in version 26.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to solve this.

The workaround was to copy $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo contents into the same directory on the Client side.